# Stack overflow exception handling xe166

Tags: c, stack, overflow

If a **stack overflow trap** occures, I would like the controller to:

- send a message to inform the user that a stack overflow occured
- do a reset when the message has been sent

I wonder if it is a good idea to reset the Stack Pointer before starting this exception handling to be sure that the procedure will be done without messing up memory or is there a better way to handle this exception?

Comment: With so little detail, your question is not answerable. Are you running an operating system? What channels are you sending the message through? What is your memory layout: where does the exception handler gets its stack space from?

Comment: There is no operation system running and the channel is not yet defined. The idea is to find a basic solution to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow exception doesn't mean anything is wrong *yet* as far as I recall from my days programming the early C167s (from which the xe166 comes I think).  It just means you are right at the end of the stack.  Indeed with sufficient jiggery pokery you can use the stack overflow and stack underflow exceptions to "page" a larger stack in and out of main memory!

So, if you can assure yourself that the exception handler needs no further stack then you could get away without resetting the SP.  You're likely to be calling some functions from it though I imagine, in which case having some free stack space might be useful :)

Your comment regarding "messed up stack" is not quite the issue - once the stack pointer has reached the end, any further stack usage messes up *other things* which may be data your exception code is going to rely on.  It sounds like you must guarantee a reset takes place, but it you start clobbering memory with an errant SP, you can't predict what might happen.

So, if it's a remotely critical system, find a way to afford the memory for an "emergency stack" then point the SP to that before proceeding with your exception handler.

Comment: I hope that a stack overflow won't happen too often so I hope to find a solution that doesn't mean too much of work :)

Comment: I thought that resetting the SP avoids a messed up memory and as the controller will be reset anyway (which I think is the only way to handel an overflow) I hopefully don't have to mind the state of the messed up stack right before the reset and after the "exception handling". Or am I overlooking a fault?